Php variable within html input
I wrote a large registration system in html/php/mysql many years ago. I had to upgrade a lot of code when php was upgraded. I have been having issues with passing php variables in html input. A registration form is mostly painted, then just stops when it hits the statements. I will extract the salient pieces here:
<form name=“regForm” method=“POST” action=“processReg.php”>

Acres of code, which all paints just fine
  <INPUT type=“hidden” name=“regState” value=“<?php echo $personFound; ?>” >
  <INPUT type=“hidden” name=“person_id” value=“<?php echo $person_id; ?>” >
  <INPUT type=“hidden” name=“rs” value=“<?php echo $res; ?>” >

  <INPUT type=“submit” value=“Submit”>
</form>

The submit button is not displayed. I am led to believe that I have some error with the hidden input. I put the code through a syntax checker, which reported no issues. Any clues?
If I remove the surrounding php portion, leaving the variables, the screen finishes painting. The submit button is there, yet blows up when the form action is executed. $res is a php array.

What is the resulting HTML page source in the browser?  Are there any errors in the PHP logs?

As an aside... Those stylized "smart quotes" are invalid HTML.  The browser may be silently correcting them for you, but you should correct them in the code instead.

If $res is really an array then echo $res; makes little sense. See: https://3v4l.org/Nut3A

Perhaps the 3 variables $personFound, $person_id, $res create invalid html - var_dump them and look what they are.

I don't know why the quotes were changed when I typed them in. Next time, I will cut and paste directly from the file.

Yeah, always copy and paste your code. Then there is no danger of typos or other problems which then distract from your real issue

@David ~ I see nothing in the logs. Perhaps that is due to me not logging them?

Anyway, as above - use the View Source feature in your browser, or the element inspector, to see what the final result returned by php was. Probably you'll see an error message or something like that, inside one of the html elements. And yeah, you can't echo an array - what would you expect the output to be from doing that, exactly?

Perhaps that is due to me not logging them...only you can look at your php config and tell us if error logging is enabled or not

@gudulkaman: If error logging is disabled, see: How can I get useful error messages in PHP?  If it's enabled and no errors are produced then the PHP code wouldn't appear to be failing, what exact output is produced in the page source in the browser?

@KIKO ~ I wrote this code 20some years ago. That $res array has worked until recently. I need to access it when I hit the Submit button.

I understand. Can't you recreate $res in processReg.php somehow? It is always safer if you don't pass something through the client's browser when you need it in PHP. Use the session to store it, if you cannot recreate it.

@ADyson ~ View Source is helpful. I had long-forgotten this cool feature. See what a 15 years from being away from the industry does? :) I am shown that is is indeed the $res array that is causing my issue.

OK. Even if that didn't crash in old php versions it's hard to see that it would ever have done anything useful. Do you use that value when it's posted back in the form? What do you want to see in that field? That's what you need to think about now

"the quotes were changed when I typed them in" -- because you forgot to disable "Smart Quotes" when you were typing here.

PHP 8 has upgraded many problems that used to be warnings into fatal errors. That would explain why old code that seemed to work now crashes. But the operative word is seemed -- the problem was always there, you just didn't notice it.

Even now, as per https://3v4l.org/Nut3A it only produces a warning. It doesn't crash it. So are you actually seeing a different error? You didn't actually tell us what you found in the View Source

Thank you for being so helpful. I feel my code is somewhat convoluted since there is such a mix of html, php, and mysql. I think back then, I was trying to organize the code to be in maintainable sections. I am looking right now at how to restructure. I think my major problem is the snippet that i showed is inside an .inc file and inside a php function. Then from there, the submit form executes another .php file. All to avoid a massive monolithic piece of code.

@ADyson ~ View Source shows the code right up to $res, nothing beyond that. That line of code is red. If I remove that particular INPUT, the screen completes. but crashes as soon as I click the submit button.

Do you mean that you see <INPUT type="hidden" name="rs" value=" and then it stops? Is that what you see? Please confirm the exact content. Maybe there's an error, but error reporting on screen is switched off?

Myabe it would be helpful to describe the registration process. Note that this is not available for external use by potential registrants. So, the web pages are not viewable without knowing the URL and having a login. Am I able to present screen shots?

This is what View Source shows.   

<INPUT type="hidden" name="rs" value="

I don't want to be negative, but not knowing the URL and not having a login will probably not deter a good hacker if your code is insecure. Since you don't seem to know what's going on in your code, it is clearly not safe. Assume you will get hacked, until you can prove that's not possible. If your code doesn't protect anything, that's worth protecting, then that's fine, otherwise consider yourself warned.

It seems your next step is probably to enable php error logging, then re-test the code,  check the log file and see what error you get. I can't see why else it would stop there other than if php is silently crashing. We can't fix it unless we know what the error message is. I can't see how a screenshot of your page would be useful at this point.

Yes, you can include screenshots in your question, but we prefer code. Only use images to illustrate something graphical, not something textual.

Thank you for the warning @KIKO. I was likely clueless when i wrote this code in 2004. Thakfully, I have not been hacked.

@gudulkaman I was likely clueless when i wrote this code in 2004...join the club, I was the same. But I've been coding non-stop ever since :-)

@ADyson ~ hahahaha. Since I switched careers, I have become quite rusty. Now, I am trying to retire. More time to play music, restore my old house, and wrestle with old code :)
